# Prisma One-to-One update Parent or update Parent and Child

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I have a Parent Child (One-To-One) Relationship like this:

```
model Account {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  billingAddress Address?
  name           String

  @@map("Accounts")
}

model Address {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  city       String?
  country    String?
  postalCode Int?
  state      String?
  street     String?
  accountId  Int      @unique
  account    Account  @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id])
}
```

I want to be able to Update the Parent Record without the need of updating also the Child Record. Furthermore, it would be great, if I can update the Parent Record and the Child Record at the same time. Right now I am getting an Error when only trying to send the Data for the Parent Record.

Here are my DTOs to Create and Edit the Entities:

Create / Edit Account:

```
export class CreateAccountDto {

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    name: string;

    @IsOptional()
    billingAddress?: CreateAddressDto;

}
```

Create / Edit Addresss:

```
export class EditAddressDto {

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    city?: string;

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    country?: string;

    @IsNumber()
    @IsOptional()
    postalCode?: number;

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    state?: string;

    @IsString()
    @IsOptional()
    street?: string;

    @IsInt()
    @IsOptional()
    accountId: number;

}
```

I'm creating and editing the Account like this:

```
async editAccount(accountId: number, dto: EditAccountDto) {
    let account;

    console.log({dto})

    account = await this.prisma.account.update({
        where: {
            id: accountId
        },
        data: {
            ...dto,
            billingAddress: {
                update: {
                    ...dto.billingAddress
                }
            }
        },
        include: {
            billingAddress: true
        }
    });

    console.log(account)

    return account;
}
```

When i try to Edit the Account with the following Data

```
{
    "name": "Test Account Create2",
    "billingAddress": {
        "id": 2,
        "city": "Dortmund",
        "state": "NRW",
        "postalCode": 44442,
        "country": "Germany",
        "street": "Benninghofer Heide 63",
        "accountId": 10000001
    }
}
```

i am getting the following Error:

```
Unknown arg `accountId` in data.billingAddress.update.accountId for type AddressUncheckedUpdateWithoutAccountInput. Did you mean `country`? Available args:
type AddressUncheckedUpdateWithoutAccountInput {
  id?: Int | IntFieldUpdateOperationsInput
  city?: String | NullableStringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
  country?: String | NullableStringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
  latitude?: Decimal | NullableDecimalFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
  longitude?: Decimal | NullableDecimalFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
  postalCode?: Int | NullableIntFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
  state?: String | NullableStringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
  street?: String | NullableStringFieldUpdateOperationsInput | Null
}


    at Document.validate (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:29297:20)
    at serializationFn (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31876:19)
    at runInChildSpan (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:25100:12)
    at PrismaService._executeRequest (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31883:31)
    at consumer (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31810:23)
    at C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31815:51
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:199:9)
    at C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31815:29
    at runInChildSpan (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:25100:12)
    at PrismaService._request (C:\Users\Simon\IdeaProjects\crm-tool\crm-backend\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\index.js:31812:22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says, you are not allowed to specify `accountId` when you are updating the address in this way. You can just remove it from your DTO and everything should be fine.

Comment: When I remove the accountId I am getting the Error "Query interpretation error. Error for binding '1': AssertionError("Expected a valid parent ID to be present for nested update to-one case.")"

Comment: Cannot reproduce that. Can you provide a minimal reproduction?

Comment: It's now working. I provided the wrong Id to update the Account and therefore it wasn't working.